# Dimmable LED bulb

Tags: home-electronics, smart-device

I am redesigning our bathroom and currently looking at two different light sources

- 12V LED spots with a dimmable LED driver (via 1kHz PWM)
- Some sort of chandelier with a E27 (bulb).

I want the bulb also to be dimmable. I found [this](https://at.rs-online.com/web/p/gls-led-lampen/1235908?cm_mmc=AT-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_AT_DE_Beleuchtung_Whoop_HI-_-(AT:Whoop!)%20GLS%20LED-%20Lampen-_-PRODUCT_GROUP&matchtype=&aud-826607888547:pla-333414383946&gclid=CjwKCAiAy9jyBRA6EiwAeclQhD9DlI0DVNNIUtTUnt1RwW-xA1QLxWSKrDxiBBeDUmoYznOSyM3RMRoCbNUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) bulb, which needs a classic triac dimmer. Since I want to control the lights using a self build controller (based on the SAM51J) I do not know the correct approach.

I was looking for dimmable 12V bulbs but was not able to find anything commercial. Either they are dimmable with a LED-driver or via "Smart"-Bulbs (zigbee or similar).

Is there a bulb with E27 which I can dim over a 12V LED-Driver?

Note: redirected from [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4908/dimmable-led-bulb?noredirect=1#comment10556_4908)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for, but I doubt you'll find a 12 VDC bulb for E27. I believe those triacs are voltage controlled though so maybe something along those lines?

Comment: And forget Zigbee or Z-Wave. Their barier of entry is too high for a hobbyist.

Comment: i) This is probably the right way. LED-Driver for the spots, 'classic' TRIAC dimmer using dimmable 220V/50Hz LED bulbs. I was hoping I can use one driver with two separate channels so I have only one device in the ceiling.
ii) I do not want to use wireless protocols. I have a controller based on the SAM51J uC which communicates with all external devices (via cables)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit over my head from a technical perspective.  LED bulbs are a lot more complicated than incandescent (sometimes that's a good thing in terms of added features, sometimes it's a bad thing in terms of compatibility with existing systems).

However, I am very much aware LED bulbs don't dim like traditional incandescent bulbs.  The room just gets darker and it looks extremely unnatural.  I'm not sure what country you're in or if these would be available in your area, but I've found the [Philips Warm Glow Effect bulbs](https://www.usa.lighting.philips.com/consumer/choose-a-bulb/warm-glow-dimmable-led-lighting) (or probably any brand bulb with a 'warm glow' effect) to be a superior dimmable light bulb.  The dimming effect is exactly like a traditional incandescent bulb.

I don't work for the company.  I'm just a person who made this discovery through trial-and-error.  I recommend these bulbs to everyone to save them from the same hassle I went through in trying different bulbs but never really being satisfied with the end result.

Also, the bulb you linked to says it's dimmable in the 'Properties and advantages' but then later says it's not dimmable in the 'Technical data of the item shown' so that's quite the discrepancy!